# Is a buffer within kmalloc also a DMA safe buffer?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I'm in the middle of writing a framebuffer driver for an SPI connected LCD. I use kmalloc to allocate the buffer, which is quite large - 150KB. Given the way kmalloc is allocating the buffer, ksize reports that way more memory is being used - 256KB or so.

The SPI spi_transfer structure takes pointers to tx and rx buffers, both of which have to be DMA safe. As I want the tx buffer to be about 16KB, can I allocate that buffer within the kmalloced video buffer and still be DMA safe?

This could be considered premature optimisation but there's so much spare space within the video buffer it feels bad not to use it! Essentially there is no difference in allocated memory between:

```
kmalloc(videosize)
```

and

```
kmalloc(PAGE_ALIGN(videosize) + txbufsize)
```

so one could take the kptr returned and do:

```
txbuf = (u8 *)kptr + PAGE_ALIGN(videosize);
```

I'm aware that part of the requirement of "DMA safe" is appropriate alignment - to CPU cacheline size I believe... - but shouldn't a page alignment be ok for this?

As an aside, I'm not sure if tx and rx can point to the same place. The spi.h header is unclear too (explicitly unclear actually). Given that the rx buffer will never be more than a few bytes, it would be silly to make trouble by trying to find out!

Comment: Maybe try structuring your code to write directly to DMA'ble memory instead of a kmalloc buffer?

Comment: Why are you using `kmalloc` for the video buffer?

Comment: As opposed to __get_free_pages? Shouldn't make any difference... They are both DMA safe. I can semi answer my own question - if I align to a page, I believe that will sort out any possiblity of cache coherency issues, even if it is overkill, without me looking into TLB stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes with provisos. (Specifically that "it's more complicated than that")

If you acquire your memory via __get_free_page*() or the generic memory allocator (kmalloc) then you may DMA to/from that memory using the addresses returned from those routines. The underlying implication is that a page aligned buffer within kmalloc, even spanning multiple pages, will be DMA safe as the underlying physical memory is guaranteed to be contiguous and a page aligned buffer is guaranteed to be on a cache line boundary.

One proviso is whether the device is capable of driving the full bus width (eg: ISA). Thus, the physical address of the memory must be within the dma_mask of the device.

Another is cache coherency requirements. These operates at the granularity of the cache line width. To prevent two seperate memory regions from sharing one cache line, the memory for dma must begin exactly on a cache line boundary and end exactly on one. Given that this may not be known, it is recommended (DMA API documentation) to only map virtual regions that begin and end on page boundaries (as these are guaranteed also to be cache line boundaries as stated above).

A DMA driver can use dma_alloc_coherent() to allocate DMA-able space in this case to guarantee that the DMA region is uncacheable. As this may be expensive, a streaming method also exists - for one way communication - where coherency is limited to cache flushes on write. Use dma_map_single() on a previously allocated buffer.

In my case, passing the tx and rx buffers to spi_sync without dma_map_single is fine - the spi routines will do it for me. I could use dma_map_single myself along with either unmap or dma_sync_single_for_cpu() to keep everything in sync. I won't bother at the moment though - performance tweaking *after* the driver works is a better strategy.

See also:

- [Does every dma_map_single call require a corresponding dma_unmap_single?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172118/does-every-dma-map-single-call-require-a-corresponding-dma-unmap-single)
- [Linux kernel device driver to DMA into kernel space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564326/linux-kernel-device-driver-to-dma-into-kernel-space)

Comment: Great succinct answer. However a few doubts:
1. Why is dma_alloc_coherent expensive? Is it expensive on all chipsets or _only_ on those with strict cache update requirements that might require circumventing that?
2. Can you elaborate more on the streaming method in similar succinct manner?